# mysqli_fetch_array returning less results than expected

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm using the code below to return and echo an array. If I define `mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_BOTH)` then my array is truncated by one result. The 1st result in the array drops off the list. If I remove the `MYSQLI_BOTH` then I get the results that I expect, but my hosting company (Dreamhost) throws this error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() [function.mysqli-fetch-array]: The result type should be either MYSQLI_NUM, MYSQLI_ASSOC or MYSQLI_BOTH in /blah/blah/blah.co.uk/index.php on line 14

What I really want is to use `mysqli_fetch_array($results, 0)` so that I catch all of the results, but do not get this error message.

CODE:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die('This is the die connect error');

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT continent FROM tour";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('This is the die query error');

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH); // was ($result, 0) to start at 0, now in error, starts at 1 missing results

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<a href="country.php?continent=' . $row['continent'] . '">' . $row['continent'] . "</a><br />\n"; 
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: This is not really answerable because you're not telling us about the nature of that first record: Is it a duplicate of the second one (which would be ok)?

Answer (score 2):

The difference in those parameters is only in how the array will be defined.

`MYSQLI_NUM` = Array items will use a numerical index key.
`MYSQLI_ASSOC` = Array items will use the column name as an index key.
`MYSQLI_BOTH` = Array items will be duplicated, with one having a numerical index key and one having the column name as an index key.

You're not losing results.

You are however fetching twice before outputting, which meant you were skipping a row... do it like this:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT continent FROM tour"; 

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('This is the die query error'); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 

    echo '<a href="country.php?continent=' . $row['continent'] . '">' . $row['continent'] . "</a><br />\n";  
    } 

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, when I tried it like this, I was again 'losing' the 1st result drawn from the db.
I'm not too sure why this is still happening. Further to that, I still get the error message when using MYSQLI_ASSOC that I mentioned above.
Very perculiar!

Comment: There is no way.  Run that query in MySQL directly and see what you're getting back.  Remove the MYSQLI_ASSOC parameter, just have the query as a param.

Answer (score 0):

You are using distinct in your query. Ditinct return the unique records only. please check your database if you have multiple continents name in your table or not.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT continent FROM tour"; 

 $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('This is the die query error'); 

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 

    echo '<a href="country.php?continent=' . $row['continent'] . '">' . $row['continent'] . "</a><br />\n";  
} 

mysqli_close($dbc);
```